# Parsing a List of Models in Play! 2.1.x

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

Given the JSON...

```
[ {"ID": "foo"}, {"ID": "bar"} ]
```

Represented with case classes...

```
case class Example(models: List[Model])
case class Model(id: String)
```

I attempt the following which fails with `overloaded method value read with alternatives`.

```
trait JsonReader {
  implicit val modelReads: Reads[Model] = (__ \ "name").read[String](Model)
  implicit val exampleReads: Reads[Example] = JsPath.read[List[Model]](Example)
  def get (response: Response) = response.json.as[Example]
}
```

What is the correct way to parse this?

Answer (score 0):

For a strange reason I did not find an elegant solution to read a json model with only one value. For 2 and more values you may write:

```
implicit val reader = (
(__ \ 'id).read[Long] and
(__ \ 'field1).read[String] and
(__ \ 'field2).read[String])(YourModel.apply _)
```

For a json with 1 field try using something like that:

```
implicit val reader = new Reads[Model] {
    def reads(js: JsValue): JsResult[Model] = {
      JsSuccess(Model((js \ "name").as[String]))
    }
  }
```

This should work but doesn't look nice :(

Comment: I've played around with various permutations of what you have here, and the problem point always comes down to the `List[T]`.  I had kinda assumed that if I had `implicit Reads[Model]` within scope that `.as[List[Model]]` would just work automagically, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  It complains there is not implicit reader for `Reads[List[Model]]` and I haven't figured out a way to write that.